# Increasing Heap size on Linux system

Tags: java, linux

I work on linux machine and I'd like to set min heap size and also want to increase the max heap size for Java. The RAM is 4GB and the current Max Heap Size is 1GB. Can you please guide me up to what value can I increase the max heap and also what min heap size I need to set for the above configuration.

Comment: use -Xmx for max heap and -Xms for min heap size as command line

Comment: You could make the maximum 3 GB out of 4 GB, but you don't need to set the minimum in many cases.  4 GB is pretty small and I would consider increasing it if you can.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, Ravthiru, Peter for ur quick response. I want to know is there any effects in the value we set for heap size on 32 bit or 64 bit. Mine is 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 3):

> **Java Heap Size** Place to store objects created by your Java application, this is where Garbage Collection takes place, the memory
>   used by your Java application. For a heavy Java process, insufficient
>   Heap size will cause the popular java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space.

```
-Xms<size> - Set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size> - Set maximum Java heap size

$ java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m JavaApp
```

> **Suggested Java Memory**
>   Below is suggested value for a small to medium Java application

```
Heap = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

Source: https://www.mkyong.com/java/find-out-your-java-heap-memory-size/

Comment: Thanks Rudziankou. Actually requirement came to increase the max heap size. So according to u upto what value we can increase the max heap size.

Comment: I think sane decisions is allow max heap size up to 1/2 you action RAM size. I would suggest increasing of RAM or rethinking GC strategies if you face lack of memory

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size

java -Xms4g -Xmx4g ClassName
```